# In Dynamic contents, complete all the incompleted html tags with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to check all those elements in my page which are not enclosed within the html tags properly. for example i have the following scenario:

```
This is the picture of my village <img src="path_to_image" <br> some other text.....
```

Here in the above string in the page which also contained the  tag after the image tag in the string and want to complete it with jQuery.
Please also note that the contents are displayed on my page from mysql database table.
Any help will be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try and run your markup through a validator:

https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I don't want to check it only if there is any tag is incomplete but i would like to complete it with jquery tag. for example i have <img src=" but as it is not complete tag, here i would like to complete it with jquery.?

Comment: Ahh I see. I think this is kinda tricky as you wont be able to query the actual DOM node because it is incomplete. You'll probably have to get the string representation of the DOM by using something like innerHTML and write a regex to extract out parts that need to be replaced.

Comment: Yes, exactly this is what i want to do. But i am not sure how to do that, any idea?

Comment: Is there any way you can do this on the server side when you query your SQL? It will make it a lot easier.

Comment: yes i am retrieving data as a contents from the table: e.g: select contents from myTable where recordNo = :recordNo